# Корректна ли фраза "Прослушивание наушников"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Добрый день!
Можно ли писать "прослушивание наушников" вместо "прослушивание в наушниках"?
Обоснуйте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **прослушивание (записи) в наушниках,** здесь прямой объект ― запись песни, текста.

**Прослушивание наушников** ― здесь объект сами наушники, а не звуковая запись.

К тому же можно подумать, что ваши наушники кто-то дополнительно прослушивает с целью получения какой-либо информации.

Comment: А слушать магнитофон можно? Объект – сам магнитофон... Обычная метонимия, скоро вполне завоюет права гражданства, ибо процент "слушающих наушники" на улицах уже зашкаливает.

Comment: Магнитофон включает в себя источник звука, а наушники только передают звук от источника. А по улице просто ходят люди в наушниках.

Comment: Это физика, кого она интересует...

Comment: Грамотная речь не может соответствовать неграмотной физике. Вот когда источник звука будет в наушниках, тогда и будете их прослушивать.

Comment: С точки зрения физики, излучатель звука находится в наушниках, поэтому именно они являются источником ЗВУКА, но ини не являются источником передаваемой информации. Суть не в физике, а в субъективном восприятии и мнемонии, как например, слушать радио (передачу) или радиоприемник. Пока еще слова "слушать наушник" звучат немного странно, но кто знает, что будет завтра? – М_Г 7

Answer (score 3):

О прослушивании наушников можно говорить (и так говорят) только в случае тестирования новинок, поступивших в продажу: чтобы рекомендовать продукт покупателю, надо иметь о нём представление.

Comment: Да, думаю, что Вы правы.   "Прослушать наушники" - значит, определить  их пригодность для качественного  воспроизведения звука. Но автор вопроса скорее имел в виду именно ситуацию с обычным прослушиванием музыки: слушать ее в наушниках или слушать наушники.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что так говорить можно, если можно "слушать магнитофон". Обычная метонимия. Лет пятьдесят назад слушали магнитофон, теперь слушают наушники. От контекста, конечно, зависит.

Comment: В магнитофоне находятся и запись песни, и звуковая колонка, а в наушниках - только устройство, излучающее звук. Более подходящая аналогия для наушников - радиоприемник.

Answer (score 0):

Наушники, присоединенные к плееру, мобильному телефону и т.п., являются - и воспринимаются современными людьми - не как источник, а как передаточное звено, 
поэтому как правило мы не говорим "слушать наушники".
Однако, возможно, есть такие ситуации, в которых наушники воспинимаются как источник,
например, когда они присоединены к розетке и заменяют собой радиоприемник или телефонный аппарат, и тогда я могу себе представить,
что кто-то "слушает наушники".

По-другому обстоит дело со словом "прослушивать". У него есть несколько значений.

Одно из них: "вслушиваясь, определить по звукам состояние кого-, чего-л. П. больного. П. лёгкие, сердце". 
Оно вполне подходит. Это проверка качества путем прослушивания. Слова "прослушивание наушников" воспринимаются в
первую очередь именно в этом смысле.

Другое значение - "слушать в течение какого-л. времени". Для того, чтобы ваш собеседник понял слова
 "прослушивание наушников" в этом смысле, а не в смысле тестирования, нужны какие-то особые обстоятельства (см. выше) и дополнительные пояснения.